# angular-file-upload update scope onCompleteItem

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

So i have a value in my scope called `$scope.selectedComponent`

Then i have the following `uploader`:

```
    var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: 'user_resources/upload.php',
    formData: [{module_id: $state.params.id, component: $scope.selectedComponent}]
});

// FILTERS

uploader.filters.push({
    name: 'customFilter',
    fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
        return this.queue.length < 10;
    }
});

// CALLBACKS

uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, filter, options) {
    console.info('onWhenAddingFileFailed', item, filter, options);
};
uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function(fileItem) {
    console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem);
};
uploader.onAfterAddingAll = function(addedFileItems) {
    console.info('onAfterAddingAll', addedFileItems);
};
uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function(item) {
    console.info('onBeforeUploadItem', item);
};
uploader.onProgressItem = function(fileItem, progress) {
    console.info('onProgressItem', fileItem, progress);
};
uploader.onProgressAll = function(progress) {
    console.info('onProgressAll', progress);
};
uploader.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
    console.info('onSuccessItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
};
uploader.onErrorItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
    console.info('onErrorItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
};
uploader.onCancelItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
    console.info('onCancelItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
};
uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
    console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
};
uploader.onCompleteAll = function() {
    console.info('onCompleteAll');
};
```

The `callback` function: `onCompleteItem` is where i want to update the `selectedComponent` object however within the scope of that function i am unable to get the variables of `scope`

My question is how will i be able to update my variable after the file has uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that the $scope is loaded in your controller:

```
.controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function($scope, FileUploader) {
```

and after that you can update the value of the $scope.selectedComponent from anywhere in this controller.

```
$scope.selectedComponent = "not uploaded";

    uploader.onCompleteItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
                  $scope.selectedComponent = "upload complete";
};
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: @MarcRasmussen try putting a console.log($scope.selectedComponent) in the onCompleteItem function, and check if the value has been updated. and also post the errors if there's any in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

You can get your scope this way

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('MyCtrl')).scope();
```

Haven't test it, but it should work.

Comment: what message are you getting?